# How to access multiple database schemas of same database using mysql spring with mybatits

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis

I'm working in a big project.
so there are multiple schemas like `user_db,merchant_db,bank_db,transaction_db` and so on...
How I use those database in one spring project?
the transaction managers can be one. I don't want single tx managers for each database. but I want to access each database in name.

as a example,
in spring server layer,

```
Add Merchant
------------
{

//step1
add data into user_db>[user_table,user_login]
//step2
add data into merchant_db>[merchant_account]

}
```

Comment: Assuming 'schema' means database, tables in the database specified in the JDBC URL can be referenced just by the table name e.g. ``insert into `table_name` values ...``. Tables in other databases must be referenced with the database name e.g. ``insert into `db_name`.`table_name` values ...``.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider How to config multiple database source in Spring.In Google or Spring Doc,should easy find solution way.